# How can I load LuaLaTeX without biber in VSCode extension "LaTeX workshop"?

Tags: luatex, compiling, biber, vscode, latex-workshop

```
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "lualatex->biber->lualatex",
            "tools": [
                "lualatex",
                "biber",
                "lualatex"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "lualatex",
            "command": "lualatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

How do you make it so that if there's no biber file vs code extension "latex workshop" will ran only lualatex?

Comment: Just run the built-in recipe `latexmk (lualatex)`. `latexmk` will execude `biber` only when necessary.